# How to disable 'experimental' warning?

Tags: vala

I love chained relational feature (e.g. `0 < a < b` that replaces `0 < a && a < b`) ... but the feature is experimental currently. How to disable/ignore 'experimental' warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `--enable-experimental` to `valac`.